# Xamarin Forms: How can I make an Image Circle in a ListView?

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good Day Everyone. I'm currently creating a simple project that allows me to Add record of an Employee. All created records are displayed on a ListView. I was able to display the records and this turns out :

(I don't even know where this Xamarin Icon was pulled of.)

[image]

But what I want to achieve is this:
 [image]

I heard about the use of RoundedBoxView. But since I'm new to Xamarin, I don't know if this is a case where I can use it. Thanks a lot guys.

Here's the code for the page that should display that Images.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.EmployeeRecordsPage"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels;assembly=XamarinFormsDemo"
         BackgroundImage="bg3.jpg"
         Title="List of Employees">


  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewModels:MainViewModel/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>

  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">



  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeesList, Mode=TwoWay}"
        HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Source="icon.png"
               HeightRequest="66"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               Aspect="AspectFill"
               WidthRequest="66"
               Grid.RowSpan="2"
               />


        <Label Grid.Column="1"
          Text="{Binding Name}"
               TextColor="#24e97d"
               FontSize="24"/>

        <Label Grid.Column="1"
               Grid.Row="1"
              Text="{Binding Department}"
               TextColor="Gray"
               FontSize="18"
               Opacity="0.6"/>


          </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

  </ListView>


    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
         Padding="30,10,30,10"
         HeightRequest="20"
         BackgroundColor="#24e97d"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         Opacity="0.5">
  <Label Text="© Copyright 2015   smesoft.com.ph   All Rights Reserved "
         HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CircularImage in Xamarin.Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769606/circularimage-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: @jzeferino Yes Sir this maybe. But I don't even solve my problem yet even if i look at that same question you've provided.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

James Montemagno has an excellent Image Circle plugin which works with Xamarin.Forms. You can install it from NuGet:

> Install-Package Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle

Then you need to initialize it per platform, same place as Xamarin.Forms.Init like:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Init();
ImageCircleRenderer.Init();
```

Then you can use `CircleImage` instead of `Image` in your XAML or in code behind.

Documentation on usage can be found in the [GitHub repository for the plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ImageCirclePlugin#usage).

**EDIT**
From your edited answer, as mentioned above, you just replace `Image` in your XAML with `CircleImage`. So instead of:

```
<Image Source="icon.png"
    HeightRequest="66"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    Aspect="AspectFill"
    WidthRequest="66"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    />
```

Modify it to:

```
<CircleImage Source="icon.png"
    HeightRequest="66"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    Aspect="AspectFill"
    WidthRequest="66"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    />
```

In this case `icon.png` comes from the Android Resources/drawable folder, you might want to bind that to something else. Like an URL in your model you have in your ItemsSource.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sir. What part of my XamarinForms.Droid should I put these codes? **Xamarin.Forms.Init();
ImageCircleRenderer.Init();** All my codes are on the Xamarin.Forms Portable part.

Comment: If you look at your MainActivity.cs there should be an Init() there.

Comment: Oh I see. I've downloaded the nuget package and added the codes that you provided. But how can I make the image a circle? I don't even know where that Xamarin icon came from :(

Comment: You haven't provided any information on how you are building your UI.

Comment: I've added the code that should display the ListView Sir. Hope it will help.

Comment: I've already added ImageCircleRenderer.Init(); on the bottom of my Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle); and change the Image to CircleImage. However, there seems to be a problem. The ListView are not displaying anymore :(

Comment: What was the issue with the images not appearing?

Comment: I've added this code Sir.  **xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"**

Comment: I have added this  xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstr‌​actions;assembly=Ima‌​geCircle.Forms.Plugi‌​n.Abstractions" . ... But i am getting this issue  
   .xaml: Error: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Ima‌​geCircle.Forms.Plugi‌​n.Abstractions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' (UI)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use this code and not need a library or other codes:

```
    <Frame 
        CornerRadius="100" 
        HeightRequest="200"
        WidthRequest="200"
        HasShadow="False"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Padding="0"
        IsClippedToBounds="True">
            <Image Source="logo" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </Frame>
```